# How to fix "List Index Our of Range" error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping a webpage, and writing the output to a .csv. I'm getting a "list index out of range" error. I think I understand what the error means, but I'm uncertain how to fix it.

The HTML code that houses the containers over which I want to iterate looks like this:

```
<tr class="featured even" role="row"><td class="sorting_1 dcLogo">
    <a href="company/company">
    <img src="URL" alt="Company Name" width="50">
    </a>
    </td><td class="dcCompanyName"><a href="URL">Company Name</a></td><td class="dcBoothLabel">9999</td><td class="dcCategories">Widget 1, Widget 2, Widget 3</td><td class="dcCityState">CITY, STATE<br/></td><td class="dcCountry">US</td><td style="visibility:hidden;display:none;">4</td></tr>
```

My code looks like this:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll('tr')
del containers[8]

company_names = []
booth_numbers = []
categories = []
countries = []

print("generating csv")
with open('CompanyList.csv','w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f)
    csv_out.writerow(["company_name", "booth_number", "category", "country"])
    for container in containers:
            cols = container.findAll("td")
            company_name = cols[1].find("a").text
            booth_number = cols[2].text
            category = cols[3].text.strip()
            country = cols[5].text

            company_names.append(company_name)
            booth_numbers.append(booth_number)
            categories.append(category)
            countries.append(country)

            csv_out.writerow([company_name, booth_number, category, country])

f.close
print('Done Writing to File')
```

When I run this, I get an "IndexError: list index out of range" error pointing at the:

```
booth_number = cols[3].text
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: row 5 seems to start with a rogue </td> and no previous matching <td> tag. Does that cause your error?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `container.findAll("td")` will always return a list whose length is 4 or more? If so, can you confirm it by adding `print(len(cols))` right after that line? If not, what should happen when `cols` is too short? (Other than crashing)

Comment: That sample HTML has a `<tr>` with six `<td>` children, but there must be other `<tr>` items in the full HTML with too few `<td>`s.

Comment: Weirdly, your code runs fine for me. Py3 and BS4. This implies your page_html doesn't always have the number of <td>s you expect, as others have suggested

Comment: Thanks all. I think this is making sense to me. There are other containers in the HTML that don't have the same number of <td>s, correct? And I can fix this using ```len(cols)```?

Comment: @Kevin I get "7" when I add ```print(len(cols))``` after ```cols = container.findAll("td")```

Comment: You have to answer the question "What do I want to do if there are fewer than six columns in the current row?"  Do you want to skip the row altogether, or do you want to fetch what you can and use placeholder values for the rest?

Comment: @JohnGordon I think I want to fetch what I can and use a placeholder number for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cols array has a length of less than the element you are trying to access. In the example

```
booth_number = cols[3].text
```

the cols array has a length of 3 or less because the array indexing is zero-based (element 1 has index of 0). When you try to access the fourth element with an index of 3, you are accessing an element outside of the range.

You can remedy this with a check for the length before accessing the element.

```
if len(cols) > 3:
     booth_number = cols[3].text
```

that way, if the booth number is not in the cols, your program does not fail and stop.

Comment: It depends, you can add it before every access to the cols array, so you would have if len(cols) > 1: company_name = cols[1].find("a").text if len(cols) > 2: booth_number = cols[2].text ...etc. Or, if the record is useless without all of the columns, you can just check for the full length before processing the row, so you could get your columns with cols = container.findAll("td") and then do an if len(cols) > 5: get your data.

Comment: So: ``` for container in containers:
   cols = container.findAll("td")
   if len(cols) > 1: 
    company_name = cols[1].find("a").text
   if len(cols) > 2:
    booth_number = cols[2].text
   if len(cols) >3:
    category = cols[3].text.strip()
   if len(cols) >5:
    country = cols[5].text```

Comment: When I add the above code, I now get an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" error.

Comment: You can add code to check for None as well. When scraping, you will often need to check everything before trying to access as you can never really be sure it is there. You can do if len(cols)>1: col_1 = cols[1].find("a") if col_1 is not None: company_name=col_1.text. Then you do this for each data item and you will just get empty values for the items that do not exist, but you will end up with your data set.

Comment: That worked! The one issue now is that my code ```del containers[8]``` is not skipping the first 7 <tr>s, but that's easy enough to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

There are not as many columns as you are assuming.

You can see how many columns there are with `len(cols)`, and based on that, decide what to do when this expected column isn't there.

Note that you'll have a similar issue with the line after that.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the lines in the .csv file don't have as many columns as you're expecting. It looks like you think it should be a consistent amount of columns so you just need to check before you actually start index the row like this:

```
for container in containers:
    if len(cols) == 7:
        cols = container.findAll("td")
        company_name = cols[1].find("a").text
        booth_number = cols[2].text
        category = cols[3].text.strip()
        country = cols[5].text

        company_names.append(company_name)
        booth_numbers.append(booth_number)
        categories.append(category)
        countries.append(country)

        csv_out.writerow([company_name, booth_number, category, country])
```

I'm assuming that there will be 7 columns as that's what you calculated the first row to be but you can change that to whatever it should be.

Comment: That worked in terms of eliminating the error, but the outputted .csv file is empty.